# JS: Оставить в элементах слова перед или после разделителя в зависимости от условия

Tags: javascript, массивы, регулярные-выражения

В хтмл-коде есть ряд button'ов, названия которых содержат глаголы для мужской и женской формы через черточку, а потом идёт какой то текст например:

```
<button><span></span>сказал/сказала что-нибудь</button>
<button><span></span>сделал/сделала какую то работу</button>
<button><span></span>уехал/уехала куда-нибудь</button>
```

Нужно с помощью Джаваскрипта оставить глаголы в зависимости от выбранного пола например:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (i = 0; i < buttons; i++) {
    if(gender == 'man') {
        // оставить в названиях кнопок лишь глаголы ПЕРЕД черточкой, при этом саму черточку убрать
    }
}
```

Если в цикле нужно пройтись по innerHTML каждой кнопки, то нужно учесть что внутри кнопок есть пустые span'ы (для других целей), которые должны остатся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

var gender = 'муж';
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  if (gender == 'муж') {
    buttons[i].lastChild.data = buttons[i].lastChild.data.replace(/\/[a-zA-ZёЁа-яА-Я-]+/, '');
  } else {
    buttons[i].lastChild.data = buttons[i].lastChild.data.replace(/[a-zA-ZёЁа-яА-Я-]+\//, '');
  }
}
```

```html
<button><span>не трогаем span </span>сказал/сказала что-нибудь</button>
<button><span></span>сделал/сделала какую то работу</button>
<button><span></span>уехал/уехала куда-нибудь</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но не для всех глаголов. Например для украинских "привітався/привіталася" не работает. Насколько вижу проблема в украинской букве "i"

Comment: @stckvrw изменил регулярное выражение в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо. Укр "i" все равно не понимает но если написать английское "i" тогда понимает

Comment: @stckvrw: тогда добавьте первым символом этот i в [a-zA-ZёЁа-яА-Я-]. чтобы было [ia-zA-ZёЁа-яА-Я-]

Comment: Да, теперь понимает укр "i", спасибо!